# Monospaced font throwing line-height out

Tags: css

Let's say I have the following:

```
<p>This is a paragraph containing some <code>code</code>.</p>
```

with the following styling:

```
p {
    font: 16px/24px sans-serif;
}
code {
    font: 16px/24px monospace, sans-serif;
}
```

Why does the code element throw out my line-height? Here is a jsFiddle that illustrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/sl1dr/chgyb/

EDIT: Upon further investigation I have discovered the the fiddle I linked to works fine on a Mac, but not on Windows. This is getting more and more intriguing as the site I am working on is having the issue on both Mac and Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a `line-height` change, it is because mostly different `font-family`'s have a different margin around the font. But `font-margin` is not something what you can change with css. So you're right, you need to change the `line-height`: http://jsfiddle.net/chgyb/2/

Comment: This is where it gets more confusing though. If I INCREASE (decreasing doesn't work) the font-size (of the code element) the rendered line-height DECREASES: http://jsfiddle.net/sl1dr/52CPk/

Comment: The `line-height` isn't decreasing you just don't change the `line-height`. The `line-height` is the height of the line!!!

Comment: That just confused me to no end, would you mind explaining that a little further?

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/fixing-browsers-broken-monospace-font-handling/) a working solution which is to set the `font-size` again and set the `font-family` to `monospace, monospace`.